# Numpy gradient with non uniform spacing

Tags: numpy, gradient

I got something wrong going on :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x  = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0,1,100),np.linspace(1,2,50)));
f  = np.power(x,2);
df = 2*x;
Df = np.gradient(f,x);
plt.plot(x,df,'r', x,Df,'b');plt.show()
```

This is what I get :

[image]

Otherwise things work ok if using linearly spaced array and not using argument x.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I am expected the red and blue to be the same. red is the actual analytical derivative of f.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Gradients match on my installation and are correct. What is you matplotlib version?

Comment: thank you for trying. Did you get the right plot with the same code I provided ? I ll check my current versions

Comment: Yes. Plot looks as expected. Tested on matplotlib 2.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because numpy versions before 1.13 expect the "x" argument to be the constant grid spacing (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html#numpy.gradient). Even though the earlier versions expect a scalar dx, they do not check for this, and the result is np.gradient(f) / x, which is a valid division. This is pretty annoying since code written for numpy 1.13 may run on earlier versions with incorrect output and no errors.